# FFMPEG when live streaming sends a message and exits after some frames were sent

Tags: ffmpeg

when doing an streaming with FFMPEG all works perfectly until I get these messages and then, ffmpeg.exe exits:

```
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Unknown error

frame= 1224 fps=3.4 q=13.0 size=    2758kB time=00:01:21.94 bitrate= 275.8kbits/s speed=0.226x    

av_interleaved_write_frame(): Unknown error

[flv @ 000001e310e8a1c0] Failed to update header with correct duration.

[flv @ 000001e310e8a1c0] Failed to update header with correct filesize.

Error writing trailer of rtmp://example.com/s/2b32abdc-130c-43e5-997e-079e69d1fd7f: Error number -10053 occurred

frame= 1224 fps=3.4 q=13.0 Lsize=    2758kB time=00:01:21.98 bitrate= 275.6kbits/s speed=0.226x    

video:2481kB audio:221kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.084671%

[libx264 @ 000001e310ad6080] frame I:41    Avg QP:10.29  size: 57664

[libx264 @ 000001e310ad6080] frame P:1183  Avg QP:13.52  size:   148

[libx264 @ 000001e310ad6080] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%

[libx264 @ 000001e310ad6080] mb P  I16..4:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.7%

[libx264 @ 000001e310ad6080] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 10.9% 7.1% 5.4% inter: 0.0% 0.1% 0.0%

[libx264 @ 000001e310ad6080] i16 v,h,dc,p: 84%  6%  6%  4%

[libx264 @ 000001e310ad6080] i8c dc,h,v,p: 91%  6%  3%  1%

[libx264 @ 000001e310ad6080] kb/s:248.98

[aac @ 000001e310a46d40] Qavg: 108.454

Conversion failed!
```

Normally, the messages I received are similar to this:

```
frame= 1196 fps=3.4 q=13.0 size=    2692kB time=00:01:20.08 bitrate= 275.4kbits/s speed=0.227x
```

Which are the expected messages. Sometimes, I received this message, but this does not cause ffmpeg.exe to exit:

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'pipe:':

  Metadata:

    encoder         : Chrome

  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A

    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)

    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30.30 fps, 14.99 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
```

What may be happening? maybe it is a problem of the RTMP server? or something is wrong with FFMPEG?

This version of FFMPEG.EXE is for windows. The programming language is C# from where I am launching FFMPEG.EXE process.

As I told, this happens after several frames sent to the server. Only once, this problem occured after a few frames sent. That is why I suspect that the RTMP server is the problem.

EDIT: This is the command:

```
FFMPEG -i - -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -max_muxing_queue_size 1000 -bufsize 5000 -r 15 -g 30 -keyint_min 30 -x264opts keyint=30 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3 -c:a aac -b:a 22k -ar 22050 -f flv rtmp://rtmp.xxxx.yyyy
```

Regards
Jaime

Comment: Command is missing.

Comment: @llogan what do you mean? Please explain better.

Comment: I do not see your ffmpeg command in your question. With no command I am unable to make any suggestions.

Comment: I added the command to the question.